# Ubuntu, postgresql, show whole running sql command

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

**System**

```
Linux vm16745 3.13.0-77-generic #121-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 20 10:50:42 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.3.24
```

**Issue**

I don't know if it is right section/forum, but I will try. Is possible to show whole `sql` command in `ps`? Now, when I try

```
ps aux | grep postgres
```

it shows me only begin of command.

```
postgres 20211  0.0  0.9 2281708 74304 ?       Rs   09:12   0:00 postgres: shop shop_prod ::1(55623) SELECT
```

Thanks.

Comment: Not in `ps` but you could use `select query from pg_stat_activity where pid = ...`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks. It is for monitoring, so I think about best solution. Is good solution `grep` from ps and in case of `postgres` command is present, run this query to get `query` via `pid`? Or it is possible to log all queries with the time?

Comment: You might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722221/how-to-log-postgresql-queries) of interest.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to query the `query` column of `pg_stat_activity` with a query like

```
SELECT query
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE state = 'active';
```

This will show the first 1024 characters of the query.

If that is not enough, raise the `track_activity_query_size` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing monitoring script, have your looked at PostgreSQL monitoring solutions: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Monitoring#Checkers

I have already used check_postgres that has a linux CLI that can be customized, that fits with activity checks.

HTH,Thomas